# How to link individual images in Javascript Slideshow?

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, slideshow

So I am fairly new to javascript. I would like to add a link to each of the images in this slideshow. There are only two images. I have tried to link them like you would with an `<a>` in html...but that didn't work since it's Javascript. Is there a simple line of code that I could add to link each individual image in a Javascript slideshow to different sites? Thanks so much. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Here is my code. Thanks to help from dynamicdrive.com

```
var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [1024, 511], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["../Images/slideshow_wakeup.png"],
        ["../Images/slideshow_2.png"]
        <!--["newappvantagemobile.com/images/slideshow_3.png"]-->
         //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:4500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 900, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Maybe I didn't get your point.

Comment: The slide show works great as a slide show. But how do I add a hyperlink to the images? for example ["..Images/slideshow_wakeup.png"], could I add something next to that so it would link. For example they would click on the image and it would take them to google.com

Comment: What does fadeSlideShow() do? Is it your own function or someone else's code?

Comment: It is a fade in slideshow that is js code. I got it from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Comment: So, when you click on a slide show image, you want it to open the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [original documentation](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) of the `imagearray` array:

```
["path_to_image", "optional_url", "optional_linktarget", "optional_description"]
```

So you need to change the `imagearray` array to this:

```
imagearray: [
         ["../Images/slideshow_wakeup.png"], "../Images/slideshow_wakeup.png", "_new", "Some text to describe the image."],
        ["../Images/slideshow_2.png", "../Images/slideshow_2.png", "_new", "Some text to describe the image."],
        <!--["newappvantagemobile.com/images/slideshow_3.png"]-->
         //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
```

I'll explain it. The array has 4 elements.

1. First one is the address of the image (as you know already).
2. Second one is the link which will be opened when you click on the image.
3. Third one specifies how the link will be opened. `_new` means on a new window/tab
4. The last parameter is the text which will be shown at the bottom of the image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this is very close to working how I want it. I put this ["../Images/slideshow_wakeup.png", "www.google.com], It works great except it seems to be looking for the link in the images folder or something. at the top of the browser it says mywebsite.com/www.google.com so it doesn't actually link to the website? How do I make it go directly to google.com?

Comment: @MaryAnderson Just put the absolute URL there. Meaning: `http://www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`

Comment: Hey, I've got a question.... What if you try to make a mapping in one image of the SlideShow, I mean setting the usemap attribute. How could one do that?    Thanks..

Comment: @inulinux12 You've got 2 options:
1. Check the JS file to find the part it creates the `img` tags. Then, append your desired attributes there. I think it's here: `var $loadingimg=$('<img src="'+fade...`
2. (recommended): Use your own jQuery function and append the `usemap` attribute to the `img` tag youu want.